# How to move UI elements in horizontal layout group in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple parent object {Buttons Holder} that has a Horizontal Layout Group component attached to it, so when the game starts I instantiate multiple buttons in the Buttons Holder so that they line up perfectly.

And just for example lets say that I have 2 buttons instantiated and I want at some point these 2 buttons to switch positions so that the first button goes to the second button's position and the second button's switches to the first button's position.

And heres what i'm trying to do:

```
Vector3 pos1 = buttonPrefabs[0].transform.position;
Vector3 pos2 = buttonPrefabs[1].transform.position;

buttonPrefabs[0].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos1, pos2, Time.deltaTime * 2);
```

I mean I don't want to snap them to their new positions I just want them to smoothly travel to their new positions using `Vector2.lerp` or something.

Since the parent object has a Horizontal Layout Group attached to it i'm not able to do that.

Help please.

Comment: Try switching their child index values.

Comment: I have just edited the post, please read the post again, thank you for your solution.

Comment: You won't be able to do this because of the Layout Group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not lerp them to their new position while the position is controlled by the Layout Group. Only thing I can think of is

- temporarily disable the Layout Group
- then move the child objects smoothly via e.g. MoveTowards
- update their child index values to reflect their new order accordingly
- enable the layout group again

A more sophisticated approach would require you writing your own Layout Group that offers functionality to let child objects switch positions. That way your own Layout Group could still keep all other children properly positioned, even while two children switch positions.